Weil representation via D-modules
I'm aware of some basic geometric representation theory results such as Borel-Weil-Bott theorem and generalization by Beilinson and Bernstein using $D$-modules.
How does Shale-Weil representation of $sp(2n)$ fit into this framework? Explanation for $sl(2)$ should suffice. Thanks.
